# What methods improve creativity at an early age?

Tags: toddler, infant, teaching

I have a 10 months old daughter and I have no experience regarding parenting at all. She seems to be very curious about the details of objects. For example when given a toy she always finds the small texts on the back or side of it and tries to touch them. She is also particularly interested in my all text books or any picture that has kind of a pattern. Is this normal for this age? This makes me feel she has the potential to become a smart person. I was wondering if this is true? And if yes are there methods to help her use this potential and improve her creativity?

Answer (score 7):

Creativity and curiosity occurr naturally in children. All you need is to do two simple things:

First, stay out of the way. A lot of modern education is actually beating the creativity and imagination out of children. 10 months is too young for this to be a problem, obviously. You just need to make sure you're not *discouraging* any of this, by forcing activities that don't need to be forced or by taking away the interesting things.

Second, keep on supplying her with interesting stuff to investigate. Different colours, textures, smells, flavours, sounds or anything. It doesn't need to be anything specifically for children. Sometimes, the car keys and the box the DVD Player came in are the best toys. Just let her play, and keep the new experiences coming.

Basically, what I'm saying is that you don't need to worry about it too  much. You don't need to *do* anything, as such. Just let it happen naturally.

Comment: I wish I hade more than one vote. :)

Comment: +1 for interesting stuff. Anything safe will do. Cardboard boxes are always a winner. Clothes pegs are another firm favourite.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as the brain develops and becomes more capable of new things, there are different activities that you can do with your child to stimulate creativity and learning.

A good book to read on the topic is called [What's Going on in There? : How the Brain and Mind Develop in the First Five Years of Life](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553378252). The author goes through different stages of child development then tells you different things that you can do to encourage and stimulate your child based on the brain-development milestones they've met.

Answer (score 1):

My daughter is the same way. My approach is to spend more time with her, playing, doing things together. At that age it is simple things like opening and closing a box, putting a small object into a bigger bucket, turning pages of a book (those soft, cloth ones are great), pointing at things and naming them.

Eventually they'll start doing things like turning a radio on and bringing a remote to switch a radio to a music channel they like.